# Reading file into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to read a text file I made into a linked list, the text file looks like this:

```
 around 1 2 1
 bread 2 4 3 5 1
 four 1 3 2
 head 3 1 2 2 1 5 1
 has 2 3 1 5 2
```

Where the first string of each line are just words from a paragraph. The first number after the word is the number of lines the word was found in, in the paragraph. Then the following numbers are pairs of (line, occurrences) in the paragraph.

For example, for the word `bread`:

It was found in `2` lines in the paragraph. In the first line, line `4`, it was found `3` times. Then in the second line, line `5`, it was found `1` time.

I am trying to create a linked list from this text file, my program looks like this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXWORD 999

typedef struct node node_t;

struct node {
    char *word;
    int num_lines;
    int paragraph;
    int freq;
    node_t *next;
};

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    char word[MAXWORD+1];
    int ch, line_count = 0, len = 0;
    node_t *node = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node_t *curr, *prev;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Just trying to store the string so far */
    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            line_count++;
            strcpy(node->word, word);
        }

        if (isalpha(ch)) {
            word[len] = ch;
            len++;
            word[len] = '\0';
        } 

        if (isdigit(ch)) {
            len = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("line count = %d", line_count);

    free(node)

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

In this snippet, I have been trying to store the string in the linked list data structure, but I have not yet used dynamic arrays to store the numbers after the word which occur in the text file. I know I will need to build this data structure using `malloc()` and `realloc()`, but I am unsure of how to do this.

How should I do this?

My desired output would look like this:

```
There are five words in the text file, 
and 9 pairs of (line, occurences)

Word: pairs
"around": 2,1
"bread": 4,3; 5,1
"four": 3,2
"head": 1,2; 2,1; 5,1
"has": 3,1; 5,2
```

**UPDATE**

I have been researching this and it seems to be very similar to the inverted index problem, where I have seen that using a binary search tree would be best.

Could I implement my binary search tree like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXWORD 999

typedef char word_t[MAXWORD+1];

typedef struct node node_t;

struct node {
    void *data;
    int *ints;
    node_t *rght;
    node_t *left;
};

typedef struct {
    node_t *root;
    int (*cmp)(void*, void*);
} tree_t;

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            line_count++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version using Binary Search Tree (BST):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct internal_node in_node;

struct internal_node{
    int line;
    int freq;
    in_node* next; 
};

struct tree{
    char *word;
    int num_lines;
    in_node* in_nodeptr;
    in_node* current;
    struct tree* right;
    struct tree* left;
};

typedef struct tree* treeptr;

void free_list(in_node* in_nodeptr){
   if(in_nodeptr!=NULL) {
    free(in_nodeptr);
  }
}

void free_bst(treeptr head){
  if (head!=NULL) {
    free_bst(head->right);
    free_bst(head->left);
    free_list(head->in_nodeptr);
    free(head->word);
    free(head);
   } 
}

void print_list(in_node* in_nodeptr){
    while(in_nodeptr!=NULL){
        printf("%d %d; ",in_nodeptr->line,in_nodeptr->freq);
        in_nodeptr=in_nodeptr->next;
    }
}

void print_bst(treeptr head){
  if(head!=NULL){
    printf("%s: ",head->word);
    print_list(head->in_nodeptr);
    printf("\n");
    print_bst(head->right);
    print_bst(head->left);
  }
}

void input_to_bst(treeptr* head,char* word,int line){
  if((*head)==NULL){
       (*head)=(treeptr)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
       (*head)->word=(char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
       strcpy(((*head)->word),word);

       (*head)->num_lines=1;
       (*head)->right=NULL;
       (*head)->left=NULL;
       (*head)->in_nodeptr=(in_node*)malloc(sizeof(in_node));
       (*head)->in_nodeptr->line=line;
       (*head)->in_nodeptr->freq=1;
       (*head)->in_nodeptr->next=NULL;
       (*head)->current=(*head)->in_nodeptr;
  }
  else{
      int check=strcmp(((*head)->word),word);
      if(check>0) input_to_bst(&((*head)->left),word,line);
      else if(check<0) input_to_bst(&((*head)->right),word,line);
      else{
           if( (*head)->current->line==line) (*head)->current->freq++;
           else {
              (*head)->current->next=(in_node*)malloc(sizeof(in_node));
              (*head)->current->next->line=line;
              (*head)->current->next->freq=1;
              (*head)->current->next->next=NULL;
           }
      }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    treeptr head=NULL;
    FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char word[50],ch;
    int len=0,lines=1;

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
            word[len]='\0';
             if(len>0) input_to_bst(&head,word,lines);
            len=0;
            lines++;
        }
        else if (ch==' '){
            word[len]='\0';
            if(len>0) input_to_bst(&head,word,lines);
            len=0;
        }
        else if (isalpha(ch)){
            word[len]=ch;
            len++;
        }
    }
    if(len>0) {
        word[len]='\0';
        input_to_bst(&head,word,lines);
    }
    print_bst(head);
    fclose(fp);
    free_bst(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Every word is held as a node of the BST and also each node of BST except from the word, holds a list with all the appearances (lines and frequency ) of the word. In order to be as most efficient as possible we hold a pointer (`in_node* current`) to the last element of list of appearance so that we don't need to traverses every time we need to add an appearance.

As an example:

Text:

```
C is an imperative procedural language. It was designed to be compiled 
using a relatively straightforward compiler and to require minimal 
runtime support.
```

Output:

```
  C: 1 1; 
is: 1 1; 
procedural: 1 1; 
was: 1 1; 
to: 1 1; 2 1; 
using: 2 1; 
relatively: 2 1; 
straightforward: 2 1; 
support: 3 1; 
require: 2 1; 
runtime: 3 1; 
language: 1 1; 
minimal: 2 1; 
an: 1 1; 
imperative: 1 1; 
designed: 1 1; 
be: 1 1; 
compiled: 1 1; 
compiler: 2 1; 
and: 2 1; 
It: 1 1; 
a: 2 1;
```

Note that the above implementation is case sensitive for example "And" is different from "and".
If you don't wish to be case sensitive just replace the line  `word[len]=ch;` with  `word[len]=tolower(ch);` and works fine.
The complexity of the above algorithm is O(n^2) which would be the same if you used only linked lists but in the average case BST is O(nlogn) which is much better than linked lists and this is the reason that it is considered to be the better.
Also note that since we must keep a list for appearances of each word the complexity would be worst if we didn't keep the `in_node* current` pointer which gives us access to the end of each appearance list in constant time (O(1)). So I think that as terms of complexity you can't go better than O(nlogn).

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int paragraph;
    int freq;
} stats_t;

struct node {
    char *word;
    int num_lines;
    stats_t *stats;
    node_t *next;
};
```

Then after you parse the string you can do:

```
ps = calloc(line_count, sizeof(stats_t));
```

to get a pointer to an array of `stats_t` structs, which you can fill with line locations and frequencies. Then you can store the pointer `ps` in your `node` struct.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a program that does what I think you are looking for. I modified the structs I was thinking about before:

```
typedef node node_t;

struct node {
    char *word;
    int num_lines;
    int *location;
    int *frequency;
    node_t *next;
};
```

This way the nodes contain pointers to arrays of `int` to store the location and frequency information. Nodes and storage for the word strings, location arrays, and frequency arrays are all dynamically allocated. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXLINE  1000
#define MAXWORD    30

typedef struct node node_t;

struct node {
    char *word;
    int num_lines;
    int *location;
    int *frequency;
    node_t *next;
};

void strip(char *pln);
void normalize_word(char *pstr);
struct node * update_word(char *pwd, int lnum, struct node *phead);
struct node * find_in_list(char *pwd, struct node *phead);
int find_line_pair(int lnum, struct node *pwn);
int list_len(struct node *phead);
int num_pairs(struct node *phead);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct node *head, *current;
    char *pline, *pword;
    char line[MAXLINE + 1];
    char word[MAXWORD + 1];
    int i, n, line_count = 0;

    head = NULL;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {        
        if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /* Read in lines and process words */
    pline = line;
    pword = word;
    while (fgets(pline, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL) {
        ++line_count;
        strip(pline);
        while ((pword = strtok(pline, " ")) != NULL) {
            normalize_word(pword);
            if (*pword != '\0')     // don't add empty words
                head = update_word(pword, line_count, head);
            pline = NULL;
        }
        pline = line;
    }

    /* Display list contents */
    printf("There are %d words in the text file,\n",
           list_len(head));
    printf("and %d pairs of (line, occurrences)\n",
           num_pairs(head));
    printf("Word: pairs\n");
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        n = current->num_lines;
        printf("%s:", current->word);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf(" %d, %d;",
                   current->location[i], current->frequency[i]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
        current = current->next;
    }

    /* Cleanup */
    // close file
    if (fclose(fp) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing file %s\n", argv[1]);

    // free all allocated memory
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        free(current->word);
        free(current->location);
        free(current->frequency);
        current = current->next;
        free(head);
        head = current;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* Remove trailing newlines */
void strip(char *pln)
{
    while (*pln != '\0') {
        if (*pln == '\n')
            *pln = '\0';
        ++pln;
    }
}

/* Convert word to lowercase and remove trailing
 * non-alphanumeric characters                   */
void normalize_word(char *pstr)
{
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    while ((ch = pstr[i]) != '\0') {
        pstr[i] = tolower(ch);
        ++i;
    }
    while ((--i >= 0) && !isalnum(pstr[i])) {
        pstr[i] = '\0';
        continue;
    }
}

/* Update existing word node or create a new one, and return
 * a pointer to the head of the list */
struct node * update_word(char *pwd, int lnum, struct node *phead)
{
    struct node *found, *newnode;
    char *pword;
    int *ploc, *pfreq;
    int index;

    /* Modify existing node if word is in list */
    if ((found = find_in_list(pwd, phead)) != NULL) {
        // add new (location, freq) pair if word not in found line
        if ((index = find_line_pair(lnum, found)) == -1) {
            index = found->num_lines;  // index for new pair
            found->num_lines += 1;     // increment number of lines
            ploc = realloc(found->location, (index + 1) * sizeof(int));
            pfreq = realloc(found->frequency, (index + 1) * sizeof(int));
            ploc[index] = lnum;        // new location
            pfreq[index] = 1;          // found once in this line so far
            found->location = ploc;    // point to new location array
            found->frequency = pfreq;  // point to new frequency array
        }
        else {  // update frequency in existing line
            found->frequency[index] += 1;
        }
    /* Set up a new node */
    } else {
        // allocate memory for new node
        newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        // allocate memory for string pointed to from node
        pword = malloc((strlen (pwd) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(pword, pwd);
        newnode->word = pword;      // set word pointer
        newnode->num_lines = 1;     // only one line so far
        ploc = malloc(sizeof(int));
        pfreq = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *ploc = lnum;               // location was passed by caller
        *pfreq = 1;                 // only one occurrence so far
        newnode->location = ploc;
        newnode->frequency = pfreq;

        if (phead == NULL) {        // if wordlist is empty
            newnode->next = NULL;   // only/last link in the list
            phead = newnode;        // newnode is the head
        } else {
            newnode->next = phead;  // insert newnode at front of list
            phead = newnode;
        }
    }

    return phead;
}

/* Return pointer to node containing word, or NULL */
struct node * find_in_list(char *pwd, struct node *phead)
{
    struct node *current = phead;

    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->word, pwd) == 0)
            return current;         // word already in list
        current = current->next;
    }

    return NULL;                    // word not found
}

/* Return index of existing line location, or -1 */
int find_line_pair(int lnum, struct node *pwn)
{
    int n = pwn->num_lines;
    int index = 0;

    while (index < n) {
        if (pwn->location[index] == lnum)
            return index;           // word already found in this line
        ++index;
    }

    return -1;                      // word not yet found in this line
}

/* Find number of nodes in linked list */
int list_len(struct node *phead)
{
    int length = 0;
    struct node *current = phead;

    while (current != NULL) {
        ++length;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return length;
}

/* Find number of (line, occurrence) pairs */
int num_pairs(struct node *phead)
{
    int num = 0;
    struct node *current = phead;

    while (current != NULL) {
        num += current->num_lines;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return num;
}
```

Note: I modified this from the previous version in the `update_word()` function. The original code inserted a new node at the end of the list, so the resulting list contained words in order of their first appearance in the input text. This version inserts a new node at the beginning of the list, so the resulting list contains words in reverse order of their first appearance. This speeds up node insertion and simplifies the node-insertion code from:

```
current = phead;
while (current->next != NULL)  // find tail
    current = current->next;
current->next = newnode;       // add newnode to end
```

to:

```
newnode->next = phead;  // insert newnode at front of list
```

I have no doubt that the code can be improved, but this does seem to work. I wouldn't say that this is exactly simple, but relatively straightforward. I ran it against this text file:

```
Three blind mice. Three blind mice.
See how they run. See how they run.
They all ran after the farmer's wife,
Who cut off their tails with a carving knife,
Did you ever see such a sight in your life,
As three blind mice?
```

Here are the results:

```
There are 31 words in the text file,
and 37 pairs of (line, occurrences)
Word: pairs
as: 6, 1;
life: 5, 1;
your: 5, 1;
in: 5, 1;
sight: 5, 1;
such: 5, 1;
ever: 5, 1;
you: 5, 1;
did: 5, 1;
knife: 4, 1;
carving: 4, 1;
a: 4, 1; 5, 1;
with: 4, 1;
tails: 4, 1;
their: 4, 1;
off: 4, 1;
cut: 4, 1;
who: 4, 1;
wife: 3, 1;
farmer's: 3, 1;
the: 3, 1;
after: 3, 1;
ran: 3, 1;
all: 3, 1;
run: 2, 2;
they: 2, 2; 3, 1;
how: 2, 2;
see: 2, 2; 5, 1;
mice: 1, 2; 6, 1;
blind: 1, 2; 6, 1;
three: 1, 2; 6, 1;
```